# Armature is not symmetrical

Tags: armature

I am trying to follow this awesome tutorial on making characters in Blender by Sebastian Lague, but I have a problem. After setting the armature as the parent of the model, only one side is morphed correctly. The other one looks weird. Its hard to describe so here's the screenshot:
Before:
[image: Before setting parent]

After:
[image: After setting parent]

There are a few errors here. For one the head is in a totally different place, and secondly, left side of the body is deformed inward, while the right one is a bit stretched. I think that the problem may be with mirroring the bones (I used symmetrize).

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: May be the armature is not in its rest pose. Did you adjusted it in Pose Mode, before the parenting?

Comment: @FFeller I'm not sure, I might have changed something by accident, how could I reset it to rest pose?

Comment: In edit mode you will always see the rest pose. To reset the transform in Blender even in object or pose mode, select the object or the bone, hold alt then hit the appropriate transform button. (Hold alt+r,g,s). If you want to make the new pose to the rest pose select everything in pose mode, hit ctrl+a and select apply as rest pose.

Comment: @FFeller I did that, but unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Please share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @FFeller I uploaded the file. Is it possible that the source of the problem, is that I am using a mirror modifier?

Comment: The twist coused by the IK constraint. To fix it, adjust the Pole Angle to 0. To fix the dislocations, remove all the armature modifiers from the meshes, and remove the parent relations from them (Object Properties>>Relation). Move them to their right position, select all of them and hit ctrl+a and select rotation & scale. Then assign the armature deform again.

Comment: @FFeller It worked! Thank you so, so much! I would have never figured it out by myself.